# How to use the jQuery dataTable plugin?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, datatable, bootstrap-4

My problem is because I can not minimize "Recursos Humanos" and "Nominas", if I use another type of table for example, responsive if you minimize it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Umds8.png)

this is with : datatable responsive[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRdK6.png)

ok this is my code where I use `cdn`:

```
<table id="employeeTable" class="display nowrap" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2011/04/25</td>
            <td>$320,800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Garrett Winters</td>
            <td>Accountant</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>63</td>
            <td>2011/07/25</td>
            <td>$170,750</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ashton Cox</td>
            <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>66</td>
            <td>2009/01/12</td>
            <td>$86,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Zorita Serrano</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>56</td>
            <td>2012/06/01</td>
            <td>$115,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Jennifer Acosta</td>
            <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>43</td>
            <td>2013/02/01</td>
            <td>$75,650</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Cara Stevens</td>
            <td>Sales Assistant</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>46</td>
            <td>2011/12/06</td>
            <td>$145,600</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Hermione Butler</td>
            <td>Regional Director</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>47</td>
            <td>2011/03/21</td>
            <td>$356,250</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Lael Greer</td>
            <td>Systems Administrator</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>21</td>
            <td>2009/02/27</td>
            <td>$103,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Jonas Alexander</td>
            <td>Developer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>30</td>
            <td>2010/07/14</td>
            <td>$86,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Shad Decker</td>
            <td>Regional Director</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>51</td>
            <td>2008/11/13</td>
            <td>$183,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Michael Bruce</td>
            <td>Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>Singapore</td>
            <td>29</td>
            <td>2011/06/27</td>
            <td>$183,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Donna Snider</td>
            <td>Customer Support</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>27</td>
            <td>2011/01/25</td>
            <td>$112,000</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>


<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.2/css/buttons.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link herf="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


@section scripts{


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script> @**@
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.32/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.32/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>

<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#employeeTable').DataTable({
                "scrollX": true,
                dom: 'Bfrtip',
                buttons: [ {
                    extend: 'excel',
                    title: 'ALIMENTOS DE CORTES:' + 'Planilla Produccion' ,
                    filename: 'PLANILLA PRODUCCION',
                    text: '<i class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></i> Excel'
                }]
            });
        });
</script>
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download The required Dependencies from the Datatables.net such as the js-files and css-file.

Or

Use the CDN links.

CDN links are :

**CSS**:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
```

**JS**:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

**Note** : use `.css` file on the top of the file. Use Script CDN inside `@section scripts{}` -- like this:

```
@section scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    //..
}
```

// In case of Downloaded files.

The Best Practice will be to include all the dependencies in the `App_Start/BundleConfig.cs` file. and then register all the bundles in `Global.asax` file.

And access all the scripts and CSS from the `Bundle.Config` file in the `_Layout.cshtml` like this:

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")   // in the jquery bundle the the datatables files are included there.
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

One thing is very important ... when all the dependencies will be loaded from the `_Layout.cshtml` page so the view that you want to access the DataTable() function... That must be using that _layout page otherwise it is not work.

And finally access the DataTable() function.

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
           jQuery("#target_table_id").DataTable({
           //...
           //...
       });
    });
```